# it's a program to add string to an array ; what is the difference between putting "console.log" inside the function and and outside the function

Tags: javascript

html

```
<input type="text" id="input-el" />
    <button id="input-btn">SAVE INPUT</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

javascript

```
let myleads = [];
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");

let inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn");
inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myleads.push("www.awsomelead.com");
    console.log(myleads);//giving the output
  
});
console.log(myleads);//not giving the output
```

see here when i do "console.log(myleads);" outside the function i'm not getting the output but when i put "console.log(myleads);" inside the function i'm getting the output. my question is why "console.log(myleads);" is not working outside the function??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that when you using `console.log(myleads);` outside `addEventListener` ,the `mylead` is empty,no value has been put inside it

It will execute immediately once your page is loaded,however when we execute it inside `addEventListener`,it will have value

```
let myleads = [];
const inputEl = document.getElementById("input-el");

let inputBtn = document.getElementById("input-btn");
inputBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  myleads.push("www.awsomelead.com");
    console.log(myleads);//giving the output
  
});
console.log(myleads);//it executed immediately,but the value is empty
```